# Moved NTFS partition with gparted - Windows access it - no files - debian sees everything

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, gparted

I dropped my recent debian partition on my Windows 10 machine.

- I restored the MBR to remove the grub bootloader

At this state all worked fine as expected: No bootloader, a system partition and a data partition - both readable.

- I started with a live disk

  - removed the Debian partitions
  - resized my NTFS data partition

Now my windows 10 accepts the data partition and shows some directories. But as soon a directory contains files it says it cannot access the directory.

Back in the live disk I can open the partition AND I cann access all files. So I think during the moving there has been a problem writing some NTFS indices or something like that? I'm not experienced in this kinda stuff.

So what can I do to make all the data accessible in Windows 10?

---

**Update (2020-02-11)**

I cannot redproduce the experience I made now. I used a second HDD, partitioned it NTFS under the Live Debian and made a backup first. My attempt was to see if that drive will be read under windows and if so to repartition the failed data partition in Windows.

After restarting my system to show if Windows reads the HDD I had, whyever, no problem to read the data partition at all.

This is kinda weird, especially while I didn't changed any bit, flag or whatsoever on that data partition.

No matter that experience I can tell my approach would've been working.

Comment: Windows respects the NTFS permission, Linux not. That can result in a different behavior. For a data drive make sure `EVERYBODY` or `AUTHENTICATED USERS` have Full Access to all directories and files in it.